# compare values from consecutive rows in R

Tags: r, if-statement, rows

I have a *datatable* and for each `datatable$Ppt` and each `datatable$nitem`, when there is "fffword" in `datatable$Region`, I need to extract the value of "fffword" and compare it with the value of the following "word". If the two values are the same, then I need a value of 0 in `datatable$Output`, if the two values are different, I need a value of 1 in `datatable$Output`.

I have tried with:

```
 datatable %>% group_by(Ppt, nitem) %>%
   mutate(Output = ifelse(as.numeric(gsub("fffword([0-9]+).*","\\1",Region) == lag(as.numeric(gsub("word([0-9]+).*","\\1",Region)), 0L,ifelse(as.numeric(gsub("fffword([0-9]+).*","\\1",Region) != lag(as.numeric(gsub("word([0-9]+).*","\\1",Region)), 1L)
```

but it doesn't work.

```
 #Ppt      Region            nitem      Output
 #1        "fffword8"        93         0 (current ffword n=8, following word n=8)
 #1        "word8"           93         0 (previous ffword n=8, current word n=8)
 #1        "fffword9"        93         1 (current ffword n=9, no following word for this ppt and this nitem)
 #1        "word2"           122        1 (no previous fffword for this ppt and this nitem and this n Region)
 #1        "fffword3"        122        0 (current ffword n=3, following word n=3)
 #1        "word3"           122        0 (previous ffword n=3, current word n=3)
 #1        "word6"           122        1 (no previous fffword for this ppt and this nitem and this n Region)
 #1        "fffword7"        122        0
 #1        "word7"           122        0
 #1        "fffword8"        122        0
 #1        "word8"           122        0
 #54       "fffword8"        4          0
 #54       "word8"           4          0
 #54       "fffword9"        4          1
 #54       "word2"           4          1
 #54       "fffword2"        10         0
 #54       "word4"           10         1
 #54       "word6"           10         1
 #54       "fffword23"       10         0
 #54       "word23"          10         0
 #54       "fffword24"       5          0
 #54       "word24"          5          0
```

Comment: Is the results above your expected output

Comment: @Onyambu yes, that is.

Comment: In some cases a "ffword" is followed by 2 "word". Is that where your process breaks?

Comment: @AntoniosK I have added an explanation next to the expected Output

Comment: You mean you check the current against both previous and current?

Comment: I need to have fffword+word with the same final number.

Comment: Why is the a `0`on `word4`? Should it not be `1` since after `word4` there is `word6` or even before `word4` there is no `word4`

Comment: That's right Onyambu, I have modified it.

Comment: Very good question. Took time to arrange things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One attempt with nested `ifelse` along with `dplyr` could provide you desired result. The approach is:

If current row has Region  as `fffword` then digit should be matched with next(`lead`) row but when current row has Region as `word` then digit should be compared with previous(`lag`) row.

In case `next` or `previous` rows are not available then `Output` should be treated as `1`.

The `digit` from Region has been just compared as `character` format. There is no obvious reason to convert those in `numeric` before comparison.

```
library(dplyr)
datatable  <- read.table(text = 'Ppt      Region     nitem      
1        "fffword8"        93         
1        "word8"           93          
1        "fffword9"        93          
1        "word2"           122         
1        "fffword3"        122         
1        "word3"           122         
1        "word6"           122         
1        "fffword7"        122        
1        "word7"           122        
1        "fffword8"        122        
1        "word8"           122        
54       "fffword8"        4          
54       "word8"           4          
54       "fffword9"        4          
54       "word2"           4          
54       "fffword2"        10         
54       "word4"           10         
54       "word6"           10         
54       "fffword23"       10         
54       "word23"          10         
54       "fffword24"       5          
#54       "word24"          5         ', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)


datatable %>% group_by(Ppt, nitem) %>%
  mutate(Output = ifelse(grepl("^fffword",Region),
                          ifelse(is.na(lead(Region)),1L,
                                 ifelse((gsub("fffword([0-9]+).*","\\1",Region)) == (gsub("word([0-9]+).*","\\1",lead(Region))), 0L,1L)),
                          ifelse(is.na(lag(Region)),1L,
                                 ifelse((gsub("word([0-9]+).*","\\1",Region)) == (gsub("fffword([0-9]+).*","\\1",lag(Region))), 0L,1L))
                          )) %>% as.data.frame()


#Result
   Ppt    Region nitem Output
1    1  fffword8    93      0
2    1     word8    93      0
3    1  fffword9    93      1
4    1     word2   122      1
5    1  fffword3   122      0
6    1     word3   122      0
7    1     word6   122      1
8    1  fffword7   122      0
9    1     word7   122      0
10   1  fffword8   122      0
11   1     word8   122      0
12  54  fffword8     4      0
13  54     word8     4      0
14  54  fffword9     4      1
15  54     word2     4      1
16  54  fffword2    10      1
17  54     word4    10      1
18  54     word6    10      1
19  54 fffword23    10      0
20  54    word23    10      0
21  54 fffword24     5      1
```